# Why won't this navbar display over everything else?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been working on a website and I can't get the navbar at the top to display above everything else. It displays above the first header and p tag but after that when scrolling more it displays under the images and headers that are in the bootstrap 4 grids. I have tried setting the z-index to stupidly big numbers, setting the position to absolute and setting the z-index to a big number again, but neither of those approaches worked. I know I have set the background of the div/navbar to black but it still won't cover up the images/text. How can I fix this?

TL;DR: my navbar won't display above any content in my bootstrap rows and i've tried everything, how do i fix this?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
    src: url(../data/Quicksand-Bold.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand;
    src: url(../data/Quicksand-Regular.otf);
}
html {
    background-color: black;
}
.container-fluid {
    background-color: black;
}
.row {
    margin:auto;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
}
.navitem {
    color:white;
}
.navline {
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.navitem:hover + .navline {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    width:100%;
}
.navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
.navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Quicksand, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ddd;
}
.navigation li a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ddd;
}
.active {
    color:#fff;
}
.navline-active {
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
}
#headerline {
    height: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
}
.no-a-style {
    color:white;
}
.no-a-style:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:grey;
}
.navheader {
    color:white;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    color: lightgrey;
    font-family: Quicksand, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#footer-bold {
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.body {
    color:white;
}
.body p {
    font-size:18px;
}
.vertical-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.nav-container {
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <!-- redacted lmao -->
  <!-- Site embed properties -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Hex - Portfolio" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://hexbugman213.net/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://hexbugman213.net/favicon.png" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $desc; ?>" />
  <title>Hex - Portfolio</title>
  <!-- meta -->
  <meta name="Hex" content="Hex - Portfolio" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- style/beanstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container sticky">
      <div class="sticky nav-container">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><span class="navheader">Hex</span>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/" class="navitem">Home</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/#links" class="navitem">Links</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/portfolio" class="navitem">Portfolio</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/files" class="navitem">Files</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/other" class="navitem">Other</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container body">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <h2>Click on any item below for more information.</h2>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" data-aos="fade-right"><img width=100% alt="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-600x450-White.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center " data-aos="fade-left">
          <h1 class="p-text vertical-align">content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center " data-aos="fade-right">
          <h1 class="p-text vertical-align">content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" data-aos="fade-left"><img width=100% alt="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-600x450-White.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" data-aos="fade-left"><img width=100% alt="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-600x450-White.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center " data-aos="fade-right">
          <h1 class="p-text vertical-align">content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="footer">
      <h3>Website designed by <span id="footer-bold">Hex</span>.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If provided answer has helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index property for your sticky class in css and set it to a high value. That will keep it above anything else.

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
    src: url(../data/Quicksand-Bold.otf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Quicksand;
    src: url(../data/Quicksand-Regular.otf);
}
html {
    background-color: black;
}
.container-fluid {
    background-color: black;
}
.row {
    margin:auto;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.navitem {
    color:white;
}
.navline {
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
.navitem:hover + .navline {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <!-- redacted lmao -->
  <!-- Site embed properties -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Hex - Portfolio" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://hexbugman213.net/" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://hexbugman213.net/favicon.png" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $desc; ?>" />
  <title>Hex - Portfolio</title>
  <!-- meta -->
  <meta name="Hex" content="Hex - Portfolio" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- style/beanstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container sticky">
      <div class="sticky nav-container">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><span class="navheader">Hex</span>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/" class="navitem">Home</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/#links" class="navitem">Links</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/portfolio" class="navitem">Portfolio</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/files" class="navitem">Files</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/other" class="navitem">Other</a>
            <div class="navline"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container body">
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <h2>Click on any item below for more information.</h2>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" data-aos="fade-right"><img width=100% alt="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-600x450-White.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center " data-aos="fade-left">
          <h1 class="p-text vertical-align">content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center " data-aos="fade-right">
          <h1 class="p-text vertical-align">content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" data-aos="fade-left"><img width=100% alt="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-600x450-White.jpg"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" data-aos="fade-left"><img width=100% alt="image" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-600x450-White.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-center " data-aos="fade-right">
          <h1 class="p-text vertical-align">content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="footer">
      <h3>Website designed by <span id="footer-bold">Hex</span>.</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
 Run code snippet
```